# Can I safely delete all these large files to free up space on a CentOS system?

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I run `find` to locate all files larger than 100MB and wonder if I can safely delete them?

Below are some examples, many thanks:

```
/home/blucel/tmp/Cpanel_Form_file.upload.Vu2iQea7tl0o8dVQ
/home/virtfs/blucel/usr/local/share/clamav/main.cvd
/home/virtfs/blucel/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/share/clamav/main.cvd
/home/virtfs/blucel/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/libclamav.so.6.1.25
/home/virtfs/blucel/usr/local/apache/logs/suphp_log
/usr/local/share/clamav/main.cvd
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/share/clamav/main.cvd
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/libclamav.so.6.1.25
/usr/local/apache/logs/suphp_log
/usr/tmpDSK
/home/virtfs/blucel/var/lib/mysql/eximstats/sends.MYD
/home/virtfs/blucel/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
/home/virtfs/blucel/var/lib/mysql/vps.server.com.err
```

Comment: This is a server you are renting I take it? Some of these are database files or related to a Cpanel installation your administrator probably did. You need to contact them.

Answer (score 1):

Many of these are related to ClamAV the antivirus software, under the control of the CPanel system administration package. But they are in an unusual place (/home/virtfs/blucel) - are you running some kind of containered system here?

Many of these others it wouldn't be possible to answer definitively.

> /home/blucel/tmp/Cpanel_Form_file.upload.Vu2iQea7tl0o8dVQ

- Looks like a temp file from an upload process

> /home/virtfs/blucel/usr/local/share/clamav/main.cvd
>   /home/virtfs/blucel/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/share/clamav/main.cvd
>   /home/virtfs/blucel/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/libclamav.so.6.1.25

- clamav

> /home/virtfs/blucel/usr/local/apache/logs/suphp_log

- web log - not being rotated?

> /usr/local/share/clamav/main.cvd
>   /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/share/clamav/main.cvd
>   /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/libclamav.so.6.1.25
>   /usr/local/apache/logs/suphp_log

- all duplicates of previous things. Either due to a symlink or a bind mount is my guess. WHY is beyond me.

> /usr/tmpDSK

- not a clue. Possibly a disk image that may or may not be mounted somewhere. If you can, and it isn't already mounted, try loopback mounting it to see what it is.

> /home/virtfs/blucel/var/lib/mysql/eximstats/sends.MYD
>   /home/virtfs/blucel/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
>   /home/virtfs/blucel/var/lib/mysql/vps.server.com.err

- data and error log for a MySQL database.

Hopefully that gives you some context to help decide whether or not these are important to you. There's no way for someone to definitively answer that for you based on just a bunch of pathnames.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can answer this but you or your primary server administrator - as these are not standard files, and are part of some custom configuration.

Some of the file names show that you are running `cpanel` - so some of these files may be ones that have been uploaded by users of the system, namely those in `/home/virtfs/`.

A file that I would not recommend removing, or atleast check and see if anything has an open file descriptor to it-

```
/home/virtfs/blucel/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
```

This is a mysql database file.

Answer (score 0):

The /home/virtfs location is full of bind mounts on cpanel and do not actually use disk space (they are hard links to user files which are accessed in a jailed shell under the virtfs location).

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/VirtFS+-+Jailed+Shell

I'd suggest reviewing this documentation, and not deleting anything in the /home/virtfs location directly.